# Image Outline showing in HTML email

Tags: html, css, email, outline

I'm dealing with a annoying issue. 
I have set up an HTML email and testing it shows me by default a border around images that are not loaded. I have an ALT-Text devined and styled, so it really looks stupid this way.

I tried EVERYTHING I could think of.

1. Put a `border: 0;`, `outline: 0 !important`, `border-style: none;` in a img-tag in the stylesheet in the head-section in the style-tag
2. Put a `border="0"` on the image-tag (HTML standard)
3. Put a `border: 0;`, `outline: 0 !important`, `border-style: none;` in the style attribute in the image itself

So I really did everything I did found here and on the rest of the the internet to delete that stupid border. Who knows a different solution? Or is there something I'm missing?

Here is the parts of the code:

```
img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:0 !important; text-decoration:none; border-style: none;}

<img src="#" alt="NameOfCompany" style="max-width:600px; outline:0 !important; border:0; border-style:0;" border="0" id="headerImage2">
```

Comment: In which email client is this happening? And could you maybe provide a screenshot?

Comment: Try 'outline: none' rather than 'outline: 0'.

Comment: Have you tried box-shadow:none !important;?

Comment: @secelite: the emailclient in which I formly test is Apple Mail on a Iphone 4S. Can't provide an image because of a confidentiality agreement.

Comment: @BillyMoat Will give your tip a shot. Tanks.

Comment: Will tried all the above, no succes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to zero out the margin and padding. Try setting up your image tag like this:

```
<img alt="" src="" width="" height="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
```

On a side note - you always need to inline your styles as some email clients (particularly Gmail) strip the style tag.

Comment: The OP has explicitly tried this and provided the code demonstrating so. Are they doing it wrong? If so, how?

Comment: @Barney no they haven't. They don't have margin or padding in their CSS, let alone inline CSS. This is the correct way to do use image tags in html email.

Comment: Aha, sorry: it reads like the point you were making was about inlining styles, when in fact you're talking about which styles to inline. It could well be a margin or padding issue – you should make it more explicit that this is the amendment you're proposing.

Comment: @Barney It is also that you don't need any of the `outline`, `text-decoration`, `border-style` or other random CSS values used. I reworded it to make it clearer

Comment: @John: Thank you for your tip. I will give it a try tomorrow. I know that CSS in most inline for Gmail. That's why I tried it both ways ;-)

Comment: @John tried it but did not work. '<img src="" alt="Text here" style="max-width:600px; outline:0 !important; border:0; border-style:0; margin: 0; padding: 0;" border="0" id="headerImage2">' is the code. Still see the line.

Comment: Sorry Julia, I misread your OP - the info I have above is for displaying the email without a border, not removing a border on a broken or yet to be loaded image url.

I'm pretty confident that what you are asking for can't be done unfortunately. Hopefully I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Check this list of properties and compare it with the rules defined for that specific client which has issues. http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/